# Getting another process variables value (or memory adress) in C++

Tags: c++, variables, process, hook

I have read posts here in stack overflow but none helped me out with this.

I managed to make a program which gets all running process and its pid, I can also get the process HANDLE if needed, anyway i know i have to hook my code to the process and this is also a problem I have to solve.

The thing I want is like:
I have a C++ program which just made with this code (as exemple):

> ## Program 1:
>
> ```
> using namespace std;
>
> int main(){
>     int var,a;
>     do{
>         cout<<"1 = Change Value, 2 = Check Value, 3 = Memory Address\n";
>         cin>>a;
>         switch(a){
>             case 1:
>                 cout<<"Variable value: ";
>                 cin>>var;
>                 break;
>             case 2:
>                 cout<<"Value: "<<var<<endl;
>                 break;
>             case 3:
>                 cout<<"Memory Address: "<<&var<<endl;
>                 break;
>         }
>     }while(1);
>     return 0;
> }
> ```

and I want to make another program, also in c++ that will hook into this program's process and find the int var memory adress by its value.

Lets say:
I have the var set to 5
I search the second program to integer values with value 5.
Than in the first program i change the var value to 10.
I search in the second program for value 10 in the list of before found values of 5.
Only one address comes with that value, and it is the another program int var; value.

So now i can make if statements in the second program based on the first one values.

Anyone can help me?

Comment: You haven't shown any of your attempts at actually doing the IPC. Just your "UI".

Answer (score 0):

Shared memory is the usual way to go. You can define a common segment of shared memory, and use offset from its beginning as the "address".

This way your code is portable.

See, for example, [this boost library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/interprocess/sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.html).

Comment: you mean set my variables as a shared memory segment?
how i do that?

Comment: @Guilherme: the description would be quite long, but you can find it at the link in the answer.

Comment: Okay, thanks, but that will only allow me to share the memory if I own the program's code? like if I want to target google chrome for example, even tho I do that will I be able to share its memory?

Comment: @Guilherme: you are basically right, the shared memory needs cooperation of both programs. You wouldn't be able to share the memory with Chrome, basically because Chrome won't anything know about it. You could however write a Chrome plug-in, which would cooperate with your main program.

Comment: Hmm thanks, thats a good increment of knowledge for me but isn't what I am looking for, I guess I found it, its probably ReadProcessMemory, but I still don't know how to use it, I want to walk through all the process memory and if the value is the one I am looking for I should return it to main, do you know how i could do that?

Comment: @Guilherme: Well, `ReadProcessMemory` is a way to go, but how would you ensure that you've found the needed place in the process' memory? And if you correctly find and modify some variable, it's never guaranteed that the variable will be re-read by the process. So the way you are going is more a way of a hacker.

Comment: Not way of hacker, I want to make a code to do things based in a flash movie, I have this website I need to send lots of information everyday, and its flash based, and there are variables in there that informe me the quantity sent today, how many more i'll need, so i want to read those values, and while i need to send more, i read my text file for the data and send they to the website via a kind of macro, got it?